# How to get access to an array in another class method?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to get access to an array in another class method. By returning it (a variable with array), but accessing to that array in another method or using it with var_dump function prints me NULL in my browser. Here's my code for the class:

```
class Rsl_Icon_For_Title {       
    public $myposts;    
    public function rsl_settings_page_get_data($myposts) { 
        $my_posts = new WP_Query;    
        $this->myposts = $my_posts->query( array('post_type' => 'post'));   
        return $this->myposts;            
    }

    public function rsl_settings_page_render () {                           
        var_dump($this->my_posts);                  
    }
 }
```

Can anybody tell me please, how can I fix my code to make it work? Thank you.

Comment: Did you write this yourself?

Comment: @Akintunde I'd say yes because I'm missing quite a few things from this class. Like the constructor for example. And where is `new WP_Query` coming from? I'm not seeing any require or include to other files. Could be an autoload function, but I highly doubt that considdering the level of coding..

Comment: Those method names! yikes, why not name them something simpler like `setPosts( $posts )` and `getPosts()`.  Schematics wise you should use camel case for public method names, but that's a matter of opinions.  Typically I try to stick with PSR-2 code standards. http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

Answer (score 0):

you must call  **rsl_settings_page_get_data();** function  in  **rsl_settings_page_render()** function.and then print **my_posts**

```
      <?php
 class Rsl_Icon_For_Title {

    public $myposts;

    public function rsl_settings_page_get_data($myposts) {
        $my_posts = new WP_Query;
        $this->myposts = $my_posts->query( array('post_type' => 'post'));
        return $this->myposts;

    }
    public function rsl_settings_page_render () {

      $this->rsl_settings_page_get_data();
      var_dump($this->my_posts);


    }
 }
```

Comment: Yes if he has defined constructor .rsl_settings_page_get_data function run at first .he has not constructor .for this must be call rsl_settings_page_get_data   function for  set myposts array.You agree with me??

Answer (score 0):

You are setting $this->myposts and returning $this->my_posts.